# Js file cannot read environment variables from AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, next.js

I've deployed a next.js app in AWS Amplify and while it works fine on my local machine I'm getting this error when I try to access any of the /api/ route:

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {
        "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
        "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined",
        "reason": {
            "errorType": "TypeError",
            "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined",
            "stack": [
                "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined",
                "    at new ConnectionString (/var/task/chunks/925.js:11169:27)",
                "    at parseOptions (/var/task/chunks/925.js:21799:17)",
                "    at new MongoClient (/var/task/chunks/925.js:26423:63)",
                "    at connectToDatabase (/var/task/chunks/817.js:30:18)",
                "    at handler (/var/task/pages/api/assets.js:191:97)",
                "    at Object.apiResolver (/var/task/chunks/925.js:36862:15)",
                "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
                "    at async Module.<anonymous> (/var/task/chunks/925.js:34836:13)"
            ]
        },
        "promise": {},
        "stack": [
            "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined",
            "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
            "    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)",
            "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"
        ]
    }
```

I'm sure it has something to with `mongodb` since the error is happening in `MongoClient` but I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Please help.

**Update:** Here's the code which handles connection to mongodb:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const MONGODB_DB = process.env.DB_NAME;

let cachedClient:any = null;
let cachedDb:any = null;

export async function connectToDatabase() {
    if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
        return {
            client: cachedClient,
            db: cachedDb,
        };
    }
    const opts = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    // Connect to cluster
    let client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI!, opts as any);
    await client.connect();
    let db = client.db(MONGODB_DB);

    // set cache
    cachedClient = client;
    cachedDb = db;

    return {
        client: cachedClient,
        db: cachedDb,
    };
}
```

**Update 2:** It turns out that `MONGODB_URI` is undefined in the above piece of code. But I've added the variable to AWS as you can see below
[image]. The above code lives in `/lib/mongo.ts` file, so it should have access to the env variables, right?

Comment: Without code it is really difficult to determine anything.  My guess is that the connectToDatabase function was supposed to read a connection string from an environment variable, but didn't find it.

Comment: "can not read some property of undefined" is probably one of the most common errors in javascript. It's not necessarily related to mongo. Somewhere in your code (check the stack trace)   there is `<some variable>.match`. You get the error when the "some variable" is empty. It might be nested: `<some object>.<some property>.match`, result of a function, etc. As Joe said - show the code or check it yourself.

Comment: @Joe Updated the code, please take a look

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, I'm aware about the error. I've searched the whole app theres no `.match` call which tells me that its an issue caused in the underlying libraries I'm using. What's worse is that I'm not able to recreate the issue locally, it only happens on the AWS hosted version

Comment: Login to the ec2 and check what's in /var/task/chunks/925.js:36862:15  and /var/task/pages/api/assets.js:191:97. Speculating, `.match` is applied to an empty string somewhere in apiResolver.  May be some empty config settings or missing environment variable.

Comment: @AlexBlex yes you were right, found that `MONGODB_URI` is undefined.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't tell much. It doesn't look like the aws console. There are some 200 services in aws. "added the variable to AWS " makes very little sense without context of what you are using and how you configured it.  Is it lambda?  ecs?

Comment: @AlexBlex the app is deployed on AWS Amplify which creates lambda instances internally

Comment: Ah, that explains why I didn't recognise the screenshot. Never worked with amplify. I'd check if the environment variables made it through to the lambda - log in to aws console and check what environment variables are configured on lambda side.  It might be out of sync or in different environment like dev/staging/prod etc.  If there is nothing obvious, try to log whole `JSON.stringify(process.env)` and compare it with amplify settings. If it's still a problem I'd suggest replacing mongodb tag with amplify-related ones to make it more visible to people with required experience.